# why the output order is changed when using `log.Println` and `fmt.Println`?

Tags: go

Here is my code:
package main

```
import "log"
import "fmt"

func main() {
    var a string = "initail"
    log.Println(a)
    var b, c int = 1, 2
    fmt.Println(b, c)
}
```

The output is:

```
1 2
2016/12/30 14:22:58 initail
```

So i don't understand why the output's order?
why `log.Println` is slower than `fmt.Println`?

Comment: looks like very special case, mostly due to bufferig abd getting flushed at the end of process. here is a link https://play.golang.org/p/xWFTHKaKzR

Comment: Can't open your link, it's Forbidden.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only difference between those in terms of its printing behaviour  is

- `log.Println` writes to `Stderr`
- `fmt.Println` writes to `Stdout`

Both are not buffered. So the fact that `StdOut` came before `StdError` is specific to  your terminal or environment.

Here is a play link https://play.golang.org/p/0cukg_a9GR